# Can I use an ODBC parameter twice?

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services, odbc

I have the following ODBC query from SSRS to a MySQL database:

```
SELECT     ID,  StartTime, StartTimeMS, EndTime, EndTimeMS, TIMEDIFF(EndTime, StartTime) AS CallDuration, CallType, CallerID, DialedNumber, Extension
FROM        `call`
WHERE     (CallerID = ?) OR
                  (Extension = ?) AND (StartTime < ?) AND (StartTime > ?)
```

When I run SSRS, I get prompted twice for the first two parameters.  Ideally, I'd just have to enter that value once and be able to use it twice.  Can I use a positional parameter inside an SSRS query twice so the user isn't prompted twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can pass named parameters to MySQL like that but I think you can create them in the query:

```
SET @number = ?
SET @EndDate = ?
SET @BeginDate = ?


SELECT     ID,  StartTime, StartTimeMS, EndTime, EndTimeMS, TIMEDIFF(EndTime, StartTime) AS CallDuration, CallType, CallerID, DialedNumber, Extension
FROM        `call`
WHERE    ( (CallerID = @number) OR (Extension = @number) ) AND (StartTime < @EndDate) AND (StartTime > @BeginDate)
```

Incidently, I think you need to put your **OR** clauses in a separate set of parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Name the parameters:

```
SELECT     ID,  StartTime, StartTimeMS, EndTime, EndTimeMS, TIMEDIFF(EndTime, StartTime) AS CallDuration, CallType, CallerID, DialedNumber, Extension
FROM        `call`
WHERE     (CallerID = @number) OR
                  (Extension = @number) AND (StartTime < @EndDate) AND (StartTime > @BeginDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the 2nd parameter hidden and specify the default value =Parameters!Parameter1.Value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).